# run a linux shell script file executing from a .jar

Tags: java, shell

I was wondering if i could start a **.sh** from a **.jar file**.

I think i would go something like this:

```
start "test.sh"
```

but that did not work.

Comment: Where did you put that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Exemplary code in your jar:

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = r.exec("./script.sh");
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) 
{
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: sorry stupid question... also the "How to run Unix shell script from java code? " did not appear in the already answer box